# Using Staad with VBS (Convert VBA documentation to VBscript)

Tags: vba, vbscript, strong-typing, weak-typing

I am trying to use a vbscript to pull data from Staad (a structural analysis program).

Staad has an API to allow this, however, all the documentation is in VBA. So I'm trying to convert the VBA to VBscript, but I'm getting errors.

For example, here is some VBA from the Staad documentation for getting the total number of nodes in your model:

```
Dim objOpenSTAAD As Output
Dim pnNodes As Integer
Set objOpenSTAAD = CreateObject("OpenSTAAD.Output.1")
objOpenSTAAD.SelectSTAADFile "C:\SPRO2003\STAAD\Examp\US\examp08.std"
objOpenSTAAD.GetNodesCount pnNodes
```

I've tried running this as a vbscript, the only change I made was to remove the data types from the variables. The error I'm getting is:

```
Type mismatch: 'GetNodesCount'
```

Can anyone offer any ideas? 
In case it helps, here is the Staad documentation for the GetNodesCount function:

**GetNodesCount**

**VB Syntax**

integer GetNodesCount (integer pnNodes)

**Parameters**

*pnNodes*

An integer variable for storing the number of nodes retrieved by the function.

**Remarks**

This function retrieves the number of nodes in the currently open STAAD file.

**Example**

Dim pnNodes As Integer

objOpenSTAAD.GetNodesCount pnNodes

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is probably that you aren't assigning anything to `pnNodes`.  In VBA, that's okay because it's strongly-typed as an `Integer` which means it's given a default value of `0` implicitly.  In VBScript, it's not given a default value because there is no type.  You could assign it a `0` ahead of time and it would probably work:

```
Dim objOpenSTAAD As Output
Dim pnNodes As Integer
Set objOpenSTAAD = CreateObject("OpenSTAAD.Output.1")
objOpenSTAAD.SelectSTAADFile "C:\SPRO2003\STAAD\Examp\US\examp08.std"
pnNodes = 0
objOpenSTAAD.GetNodesCount pnNodes
```

Most likely, though, your intention is *not* to have this value be `0` (I'm just guessing), which means this conversion process has helped you find a bug :)

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this and I'm still getting the same error. I think you have the right idea though, it seems like the type mismatch error is indicating that it won't assign the value because the variable is not declared as an integer.

Comment: Try changing `objOpenSTAAD.GetNodesCount pnNodes` to `objOpenSTAAD.GetNodesCount CInt(pnNodes)`.

Comment: Yup, that got rid of the error, thanks. But now my problem is that it didn't actually assign pnNodes a new value, it still outputs `0`

That could be a different problem though. It could be a problem actually accessing the results from the file.

Comment: Right, like I said, you need to set the correct value before using it.  Please accept this answer if you're happy with it.

Comment: Ah i see. Yea, the intent of the function is to pull the number of nodes from the .std file and assign that number to the pnNodes variable. So you believe this is a bug, and that it can't actually be done in VBScript?

Answer (score 0):

Using CInt(pnNodes) as a parameter passes a function's result, not a writable variable, to .GetNodesCount. Voodoo, but easy to test:

```
Dim objOpenSTAAD : Set objOpenSTAAD = CreateObject("OpenSTAAD.Output.1")
Dim pnNodes : pnNodes = CInt(0) ' initialized to sub type Integer
Dim nNodes ' uninitialized (Empty)
objOpenSTAAD.SelectSTAADFile "C:\SPRO2003\STAAD\Examp\US\examp08.std"
objOpenSTAAD.GetNodesCount pnNodes ' may work
nNodes = objOpenSTAAD.GetNodesCount(pnNodes) ' fallback
```

**Update wrt comment:**

As you said using `objOpenSTAAD.GetNodesCount CInt(pnNodes)` "got rid of the error", try

```
nNodes = objOpenSTAAD.GetNodesCount(CInt(pnNodes))
```

and hope that `nNodes` gets the result that couldn't be written to `CInt(pnNodes)`.

**On third thought:**

According to [this post](http://communities.bentley.com/products/structural/structural_analysis___design/f/5932/t/33489), the required data type for the pnNodes parameter **may** be **Long** (instead of Integer). So try the above variations with `CLng` instead of `CInt`.

Comment: Hmm, I'm still getting the type mismatch error with both of those last two lines

Comment: Using `nNodes = objOpenSTAAD.GetNodesCount(CInt(pnNodes))` seems to pass a value of `1` to `nNodes`. Which is odd, because the value should be `16`. But it's progress anyway. Using `CLng` doesn't seem to have any affect, it still passes a value of `1` using the above method, and gives me a type mismatch error when I try it with the other methods you suggested. However, I tried the code in VBA and it only works correctly when I use `Dim pnNodes As Long`. I get the same type mismatch error when I use `Dim pnNodes As Integer`, so it seems to be true that the type should be `Long`.